# How to getAssets in a service?

Tags: android

I fail to find out how to `getAssets` in a service.

for example the receiver:

```
public class BroadcastReceiverOnBootComplete extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, AndroidServiceStartOnBoot.class);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
            } else {
                context.startService(serviceIntent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the `AndroidServiceStartOnBoot` class, how to get `getContext().getAssets().open("server.crt");` ?

Thanks a lot.

**Edited:**

The question is not how to call `getAssets` in `BroadcastReceiverOnBootComplete` class, instead, the question is how to `getAssets` in the service `AndroidServiceStartOnBoot` class.

The reason why I posted `BroadcastReceiverOnBootComplete` class is because that is how I call `AndroidServiceStartOnBoot` class. Sorry that it's kinda misleading. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onReceive gives you the context in your broadcast receiver class

```
public abstract void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
```

from there, you can use it directly or assign it to your class level variable and you'll be able to use it in other methods as well

```
Context myContext = null;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //here you can access to context directly
    context.getAssets().open("MY_FILE");
    //or you can save it in your class level variable
    myContext = context;
    // now you can use this myContext to other methods of this class
}
```

> **Edit**

[Service](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) is an inherent of [Context](http://d.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

So in Service, you can directly do like this...

```
Context context = this;
```

Comment: I think I made my question clear, but I didn't. I want to use `context` in the class `AndroidServiceStartOnBoot` which extends `Service` in another file. I know I can use `context` in `BroadcastReceiverOnBootComplete` class without any problems. thanks.

Comment: The reason why I posted `BroadcastReceiverOnBootComplete` class is because that is how I call `AndroidServiceStartOnBoot` class. The problem is how to getAssets in the service `AndroidServiceStartOnBoot` class. thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have marked it as the answer. :)

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You already have `context`
did you try this?
`context.getAssets().open("FILE_NAME");`
it works for me

[image]

Comment: post code as answer rather than posting it as image.

Comment: i meant code from that image part. it will be helpful for other users. :)

Comment: I think I made my question clear, but I didn't. I want to use `context` in the class `AndroidServiceStartOnBoot` which extends `Service` in another file. I know I can use `context` in `BroadcastReceiverOnBootComplete` class without any problems. thanks.

Comment: I think you can send in to `AndroidServiceStartOnBoot` Activity by Intent or create a `public static Context` in `BroadcastReceiverOnBootComplete` class and fill it in `onReceive` method, now you can use it in `AndroidServiceStartOnBoot ` by static context